# jndi lookup routine?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I've got a java se aplication that lookup for remote bean and executes methods of this object. Is there a way to lookup just once and then use this object or i have to lookup every time ?

I was trying to make it public object for class but when i call ive got an error.

```
public class AttendanceRegisterClient {
public static StudentBeanRemote remoteObj;
...
ArrayList<Student> listaStudentow = AttendanceRegisterClient.remoteObj.listaStudentow();
```

The Error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:AttendanceRegisterBean,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@53511634
```

if i call jndi lookup again it works but i dont want to do it all the time. Is there a way to pass around this object ?

Comment: Is it a stateful bean, or a stateless one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer Updated:**

**Your Question:** Is there a way to lookup remote object just once and then use this object in the client every time, without re-doing the lookup ?

**Answer:** Yes, its possible through `Service Locator Pattern`. This article describes top to bottom including examples. >> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servicelocator-137181.html

Comment: It's not about using this list, It's about using remote class freely. I want to use remoteObj methods all around the app.

Comment: This is propably what i'm looking for but this is huge... I think ill better crate a class which do the lookup and return remote object so i can call it where i want. But anyway thanks for this one.

Comment: Yes, to understand this pattern, it may take time. Or else you can just call a method and do the look up as you said.